# Custom UINavigationBar Graphic with Reorienting

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

So I'm successfully setting a custom graphic (iOS 5) in my app delegate with this code (ruby motion syntax):

```
navbar = UIImage.imageNamed "navbar.png"
navbutton = UIImage.imageNamed("navbutton.png").resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,5,0,5))
navbackbutton = UIImage.imageNamed("navback.png").resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,14,0,5))

UINavigationBar.appearance.setBackgroundImage(navbar, forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault)
UIBarButtonItem.appearance.setBackgroundImage(navbutton, forState:UIControlStateNormal, barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault)
UIBarButtonItem.appearance.setBackButtonBackgroundImage(navbackbutton, forState:UIControlStateNormal, barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault)
```

Easy enough. The only problem is that now I'm adding reorientation support and when the view goes landscape, the navbar image is kept 320px wide and repeated to fill the width of the top of the screen... The buttons are repositioned, but the navbar isn't strected dynamically...

How can I fix this?

I know that **didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(orientation)** is called after the orientation is completed, so if I need to call some sort of UINavBarRefactor method, I assume that's the place to do it?

PS: If it's helpful, I used [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12320/photoshop-for-developers-making-a-leather-navigation-bar) to learn how to stylize the nav bar. Though, you shouldn't need that too much; I've shown you all the code involved in that tutorial above ^^.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another bar metrics for landscape mode.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance.setBackgroundImage navbar_image,
  forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault
UINavigationBar.appearance.setBackgroundImage navbar_image_landscape,
  forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone
```

The same for other options.